# React: Appending Text to a TextArea

Tags: reactjs, forms, class, append, textarea

I wanted to ask how I could append the output variable (which I get through the post call with Axios)   to the textarea, which takes the input variable as its value.

I just have literally no idea how to do such a thing ...

I want to get the same result shown in the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcyBYfK6gfY

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";



import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const TRANSLATE_API_URL = "/translate";




class Interface extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: "",
      output: "",
      buttonText: "Submit",
      description: "Description",
    };
    // Bind the event handlers
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);


  }





  handleInputChange(e) {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let body = {
      prompt: this.state.input
    };
    axios.post(TRANSLATE_API_URL, body).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
      this.setState({ output: text });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <head />
        <body style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
          <div
            style={{
              margin: "auto",
              marginTop: "80px",
              display: "block",
              maxWidth: "500px",
              minWidth: "200px",
              width: "50%"
            }}
          >
          
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
              <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">            
                <Form.Label>{this.state.description}</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  as="textarea"
                  className="tarea"
                  placeholder="Enter text"
                  value={this.state.input}
                  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                ></Form.Control>
              </Form.Group>

              <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                {this.state.buttonText}
              </Button>
            </Form>

            {this.state.output}
            
          </div>
        </body>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Interface;
```

---

This is the error message I get

```
←→1 of 57 errors on the page
TypeError: Cannot read property 'input' of undefined
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/mario/Desktop/Vs projects/gpt3-sandbox-1/src/components/Interface.js:51
  48 |      let timerDelay = 0;
  49 |      text.split(" ")
  50 |        .forEach(word => setTimeout(function(){
> 51 |            this.setState({ input: this.state.input + word });
     | ^  52 |          },timerDelay),
  53 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only one state property as the textarea value.

To keep the previous text and add the Axios response to it, I would try:

```
this.setState({ input: this.state.input + text });
```

Instead of:

```
this.setState({ output: text });
```

---

To create the word by word add effect, try this:

```
let thisComponent = this;
axios.post(TRANSLATE_API_URL, body).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
  
  let wordDelay = 100  // Add a word every 100ms
  
  let timerDelay = 0
  text.split(" ")
    .forEach(word => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        thisComponent.setState({ input: thisComponent.state.input + " " + word });
      },timerDelay);
      timerDelay += wordDelay;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Just one more thing: I even want to create the text typing effect shown in the video. A friend of mine said to me that I should try,after the axios response, to split the text using .split( “ “), the length of this array is how many words are in the response.Then to create a for loop that will loop for this length, every iteration should add the next word to a variable and then set the state. The problem is that I can't translate it to code... Any help??

Comment: Sure... I edited with a `forEach` loop that sets a `setTimeout` for each word.

Comment: Thanks again. Actually it shows me some error messages

Comment: ')' expected.        Declaration or statement expected.       Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.       ';' expected.

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't know i did this "more than a typo" in my answer. See edit. The `function(){` was missing... So weird. I can't explain.